# FutureWarning: The frame.append method is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future

Tags: pandas

Hola estoy intentando contruir una matriz y me aparece el siguiente mensaje **FutureWarning: The frame.append method is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future**

como podria cambiar el uso del df.append

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['nombre_archivo', 'codigo', 'score'])
for obj in response.text_annotations:
    df = df.append(
            dict(
                nombre_archivo=data_file,
                codigo=busqueda,
                score=obj.score
            ), ignore_index=True
        )
```

Comment: Bienvenido Esteban a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 1):

Buen día,

Podrías reemplazarlo por el método `concat()` [(documentación)](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)

Como no pusiste los datos completos en tu código tuve que crear un ejemplo genérico que tendrás que adaptar a tus necesidades

En tu pregunta tienes un diccionario y lo agregas a un `dataframe` existente, en el ejemplo también cree un diccionario y lo agrego a `df` con `concat()`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['nombre_archivo', 'codigo', 'score'])
d = {'nombre_archivo': 'a', 'codigo': 1, 'score': 2}
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(d, index=[0])], ignore_index=True)
print(df)
```

Esto devuelve

```
    nombre_archivo  codigo  score
0   a               1       2
```